# Display records for a week in gridview asp.net with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net

In database i have a column named "Taskdate","Taskname","Tid" of table "tbltask", if i open my gridview It must display this week assigned tasknames i.e) if my taskdate contains any records between 6th october and 11th it must display those records in gridview if i open that gridview next week from it must display next week records alone

I tried a query for this in MS SQL but dono how to do the same in  MYSQL

MS SQL QUERY #1

```
Select * from Task where Tdate >= dateadd(day, 2-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(datetime,getdate())) AND tdate <  dateadd(day, 9-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(datetime,getdate()))
```

MS SQL QUERY #2

```
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE '2014-10-08' BETWEEN DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK, 0, Tdate), 0) AND DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK, 0, Tdate) + 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Previous week's Data**

```
SELECT * FROM Task
WHERE Taskdate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND Taskdate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

**Current week's data**

```
SELECT * FROM Task
    WHERE YEARWEEK(Taskdate) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
```